# how to unit testing delay-sign assemblies using nunit

Tags: .net, nunit

We have a project that all assemblies are delay-signed. The development machines are set to skip verification using `sn.exe` tool :

```
sn.exe -Vr *,PUBLIC_KEY_TOKEN_HERE
```

If we test those assemblies using nunit (GUI version), the test won't work (all tests are failed) because of delay-signed. But if those assemblies are re-signed, the test works. We're all know that to re-sign an assembly, we need private public key pair file (e.g. *mycompany.snk*). We don't think it's a good practice give the *mycompany.snk* file to all developers.

Is there any solution so that every developer can unit-testing their assemblies without re-resigning or without the need of *mycompany.snk* file ?

Comment: Is the issue just the GUI runner?  Does the CLI runner not work?  I ask because I'm doing the same thing (delay-signing) all my assemblies, using sn.exe to skip verification, and can run NUnit tests just fine with the CLI runner.  I stay away from the GUI runner so I don't know if I have the same issue or not.  Can try if you would like.

Comment: I only test on GUI runner. Based on your comment, it seem the problem only exist on GUI runner.

Answer (score 3):

Are you by any chance developing on a 64 bit version of Windows? We had a similar issue some time ago, where we were delay-signing assemblies but they were not loading correctly during unit testing. The problem turned out to be because we were developing on 64 bit windows. It turns out that there are two sn.exe programs, one for 32 bit and one for 64 bit. (The 64 bit version is located in a directory "x64" below the bin directory for the 32 bit executable in the windows SDK -- I am not on a development machine at the moment, sorry, so I cannot give you the exact path from memory). What we do is use the "sn -Vr" command using the 32 bit version, and then run the same command using the 64 bit version and everything works.